# WP plugin: Alt-Ergo Syntax Error

Tags: frama-c

For the below C function, I'm getting syntax errors from Alt-Ergo for the latest version of Frama-c.

```
frama-c -wp -wp-rte -lib-entry  RoundNearestFive.c   -wp-out temp -wp-model="nat, real"
```

I'm not sure what is wrong in this generated line:

```
 ...
      let r_0 = dat_0 / 5.0e0 : real in   /* syntax error here */
    ...
```

### C function under analysis

```
typedef unsigned short int uint16;


/*@
  @ requires 0<=dat<= 300;
*/
uint16 RoundNearestFive(float dat)
{
    uint16 result= 0;
    float fra = 0;

    result = (uint16)(dat/5);

    fra = dat - (float)result*5; // fractional part of the input

    if (fra < 2.5)
        result = (uint16) (dat-fra);
    else
        result = (uint16) (dat+(5-fra));

        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried Alt-Ergo (version 0.95.2 and trunk) on the formula below and I got no syntax error. Are you using an old version of Alt-Ergo ? Or maybe the syntax error is elsewhere.

--

logic dat_0 : real

goal g:
  let r_0 = dat_0 / 5.0e0 : real in   (* syntax error here *)
  false

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Alt-Ergo via Frama-c. My version of alt-ergo is 0.94 according to alt-ergo -v comment.

Comment: @Mohammed: Did you run Frama-c as I did with the same options? I'm running it on Ubuntu 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 3):

The [WP user manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-wp-manual.pdf) explicitly states that versions of Alt-Ergo prior to 0.95 are not supported (see page 21).

Comment: OK. I did not pay so close attention to the version number. It works now.